# Junit4 test implementation with parameters passed from XML, (attribute value + nodevalue)?

Tags: java, xml, junit4, parameterized

I know I can hardcode it (parse xml, extract), but is there a way to feed (attribute value + nodevalue) like it is done with Feed4TestNG (it currently support only csv, and excel files)?

I am new to Java, and any expert insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of a `@Parameters` is not limited to data only, you are able to use any java code you like in this method, including throwing exceptions:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws IOException {
    List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    // replace getClass() with <nameofclass>.class
    try(InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()) { 
        //parse body here
        data.add(new Object[]{attribute, value});
    }
    return data;
}
```

Depending on what XML framework you use, you need to parse your XML nodes, and put it in the list, that you are going to return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I cannot use this in static, but I got the main idea.  I was hoping to do something like this https://dzone.com/articles/data-driven-tests-junit-4-and

Comment: That also uses static for the `@Parameters` from the test class?

Comment: You mean the example right?
I am bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I end up doing here:

Please submit your correction if you think I can improve my code.
.

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DataDrivenTests {

```
private String c;
private String b;
private static Collection<Object[]> a;
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> xmlData() throws IOException{

        File file = new File("xmlfile.xml");
        InputStream xml1 = new FileInputStream(file);
        return  new xmlData(xml1).getData();

}



public DataDrivenTests(String c, String b) {
    super();
    this.c = c;
    this.b = b;


}


@Test
public void shouldCalculateATimesB() {
    boolean assertion = false;

    if(c.equals(Parser.parse("Parse this string to Attribute and Value"))){
        assertion = true;

    }

    assertTrue(assertion);


}
```

}

xmlData.java

public class xmlData{

```
private transient Collection<Object[]> data = null;

public xmlData(final InputStream xml)throws IOException{

    this.data = loadFromXml(xml);

}

public Collection<Object[]> getData(){

    return data;
}



private Collection<Object[]> loadFromXml(final InputStream xml)
        throws IOException {
List <Object[]> ism_code_map = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("//e");


    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int i =0; i< nodes.getLength(); i++){

        Node nNode = nodes.item(i);
        //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element:" + nNode.getTextContent());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


                    if(eElement.getAttribute("attrname") != null && !eElement.getAttribute("attrname").isEmpty()){

                        code_map.add(new Object[]{"attrname",eElement.getAttribute("attrname")});

                    }


    }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(SAXException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(XPathExpressionException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


return code_map;

}
```

}